# sum product accumulative in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need to apply the below module in power bi as its accumulative sum product.

Note that:

- The result of accumulative in front of each cell will be deblending on above cells sum as the below photo I'm showing what I need for excel formula, but I can't apply it for power bi or power query.

I try to appl the below but do not get what I need.

```
Measure: =
DIVIDE ( 
    SUMX ( 
        'Table',
        'Table'[cost] * 'Table'[number]
    ),
    SUM ('Table'[number])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your data as a minimal reproducible sample and not as a picture.

Comment: You need an index column for this to make any sense - is that in your data? Power BI has no intrinsic concept of «row number».

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward to do in Power Query using the `List.Accumulate` function:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("RczLDUAhCETRXli7UOQjtRj6b+OBvITdnNxk7gVChAEGPmKfHRvnA1OGqAmR1VChwNIqSF1YtA/kcIIK88F+WKIOtA42uH8=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Numner A" = _t, #"Number B" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Numner A", Int64.Type}, {"Number B", Int64.Type}}),

    #"SumProduct" = List.RemoveFirstN(List.Accumulate(List.Positions(#"Changed Type"[Numner A]), 
        {0}, 
        (state, current)=> 
        state & {List.Last(state) + (#"Changed Type"[Numner A]{current} * #"Changed Type"[Number B]{current})}),1),

    #"Sum" = List.RemoveFirstN(List.Accumulate(#"Changed Type"[Number B],
        {0}, 
        (state, current)=> 
        state & {List.Last(state)+current}),1),
    
    #"Accumulate" = List.Accumulate(
        List.Positions(#"SumProduct"),
        {}, 
        (state, current)=> 
        state & {#"SumProduct"{current} / #"Sum"{current}}),

    #"Add Accumulate Column" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type")
        & {#"Accumulate"},
        type table[Numner A=Int64.Type, Number B = Int64.Type, Accumulated = number]
    )
    
in
    #"Add Accumulate Column"
```

***Results from your data***
[image]